# Android Nexus 5x (and maybe other devices) ambient mode

Tags: android, refresh, ambient

Is there anyway to refresh my widgets if they are placed in ambient screen (see attachment) on Nexus 5x, 6P and maybe other devices.
I need to refresh data **once in a minute**.

[image]